# In Dark Knight, Is Coleman Reese more than he appears?

Tags: dc, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight

On the Batman wiki and elsewhere, there's mention of the possibility that Coleman Reese,

> the accountant who discovers Batman's secret identity in Dark Knight, [could be the Riddler](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Coleman_Reese). The key is his name: "Mr. Reese" == "Mysteries".

This strikes me as interesting, but thin. On the other hand, I haven't seen a firm refutation anywhere, either. Does anyone have any further details or insight?

Comment: Sorry, but I think this is too localized. It will be either answered in the sequel (in which case we don't know the answer now at all, and will be "trivia" when it comes out); or any answer will be merely a baseless guess and not a good fit for SE.

Comment: He doesn't seem to exhibit any of Edward Nigma's characteristic traits of an exceptional intellect (he merely stumbled upon the information by chance not through deductive reasoning) He doesn't display any obsession with puzzles or riddles either.  Then again I'm inclined to side wtih @DVK in that this question is unanswerable based on the lack of available information.

Comment: “This strikes me as interesting, but thin.” [Interesting, but thin](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/69/Riddler_(DC_Animated_Universe).jpg), you say?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Mr. Reese was not addressed in The Dark Knight Rises, which is stated to be the end of the movie continuity in which he appeared. Barring a new director deciding to make movies in the same continuity, I think we can definitively say that Coleman Reese exists only as a sub-plot of The Dark Knight. Perhaps to address the inherent absurdity that nobody guesses that Batman is Bruce Wayne, and perhaps to help set up John Blake's similar deduction in The Dark Knight Rises.

Comment: COMICS SPOILER ALERT: Could also be a nod to the comics, where The Riddler does independently figure out Batman’s identity, in the ‘Hush’ storyline.